# swiftui Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.Text' (0x2211789e8) to 'SwiftUI._ViewModifier_Content<User.PopUpViewModifier>

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a modifier that builds a sheet with content on any View.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var open: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            
            Button("Open sheet") {
                open.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .popUpModifier(isPresented: $open) {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the modifier:

```swift
struct PopUpViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var content: Content
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: {UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium).impactOccurred()}) {
                content
            }
    }
}
```

And here's the View's extension:

```swift
extension View {
    func popUpModifier<Content: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, content: @escaping () -> Content) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(PopUpViewModifier(isPresented: isPresented, content: content() as! PopUpViewModifier.Content))
    }
}
```

Whenever I run it I get a fatal error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.Text' (0x2211789e8) to 'SwiftUI._ViewModifier_Content<User.PopUpViewModifier>
```

It happens no matter which content I include in the modifier content brackets.
Also - without `content() as! PopUpViewModifier.Content)` XCode won't compile and raise alert

> Cannot convert value of type 'Content' to expected argument type 'PopUpViewModifier.Content' (aka '_ViewModifier_Content')

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the `content` that a `ViewModifier` normally takes (ie the content that it modifies) with the content that you're attempting to show in your popup.

Right now, you're trying to use *one* variable for both, presenting a sheet with that `content` from the `content` -- basically, recursion.

Setting up a separate variable for the sheet content solves this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var open: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            
            Button("Open sheet") {
                open.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .popUpModifier(isPresented: $open) {
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
    }
}

struct PopUpViewModifier<T: View>: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var popupContent: () -> T
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, onDismiss: {UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .medium).impactOccurred()}) {
                popupContent()
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func popUpModifier<T: View>(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, popupContent: @escaping () -> T) -> some View {
        self
            .modifier(PopUpViewModifier(isPresented: isPresented, popupContent: popupContent))
    }
}
```